# Creating a txt file and viewing it in the File manger

Tags: android, file, file-manager, internal-storage

I have created an android app that gets input from user through `EditText` and writes them to `name.txt` file in phone's internal storage. Is it possible to open the text file in phone's file manager? I tried to get the file path using `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+FILE_NAME`. But couldn't locate the file in file manager.

Comment: You need to use External storage if you want another app like File Manager to access the file.  Internal storage is only readable by your app.

Comment: Hi @EJK, Thanks for your answer. If in case the phone doesn't have external storage, then how to handle this? Any other ways?

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.  _Many devices now divide the permanent storage space into separate "internal" and "external" partitions. So even without a removable storage medium, these two storage spaces always exist_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use External storage if you want another app like File Manager to access the file. Internal storage is only readable by your app.

In the comments you ask a valid question - *"What if the phone doesnt have external storage...?"*.   That is not really a concern today.  See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files:

> Many devices now divide the permanent storage space into separate
>   "internal" and "external" partitions. So even without a removable
>   storage medium, these two storage spaces always exist...

==========

So change your above code to this:

```
getExternalFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+FILE_NAME
```

`getExternalFilesDir` is a method from the `android.content.Context` class.  So this call will work from your activity class which is a `Context`.

=============

Further supporting the choice of external storage is the following, also from https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.

> Internal storage is best when you want to be sure that neither the
>   user nor other apps can access your files.
>
> External storage is the best place for files that don't require access
>   restrictions and for files that you want to share with other apps or
>   allow the user to access with a computer.

Answer (score 1):

there is private storage for each app that can be accessed from the app itself and then public storage /sdcard/... that other app can access too (it needs to get Storage Permission from system)
this method will save a content in a file in private storage of app

```
public void saveFile(String fileName, String content) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fOut.write((content).getBytes());

            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: But how to save them to External Storage?